# javascript 'countdown' is not defined error

Tags: javascript

I keep getting 'countdown is not defined' with this line

```
  var timeout = setTimeout('countdown()',1000);
```

It should loop the `function countdown()` every second.  How do i solve this?

```
function countdown() {

var until = $('.time-elapsed').attr('data-time');
var nextmonth = new Date(until);
var now = new Date();
var timeDiff = nextmonth.getTime() - now.getTime();

if(timeDiff <=0) {
var nextmonth = new Date(until);
}

var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
var days =  Math.floor(hours / 24);

hours%=24;
minutes%=60;
seconds%=60;

$('.time-elapsed').find('ul:eq(0)').find('li:eq(1)').html(days);
$('.time-elapsed').find('ul:eq(1)').find('li:eq(1)').html(hours);
$('.time-elapsed').find('ul:eq(2)').find('li:eq(1)').html(minutes);
$('.time-elapsed').find('ul:eq(3)').find('li:eq(1)').html(seconds);

var timeout = setTimeout('countdown()',1000);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a string as the first parameter of setTimeout. Use a function intead:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(countdown,1000);
```

And I suggest you to use `setInterval(countdown,1000)` and remove the `setTimeout(countdown,1000)` in the bottom of your function. `setInterval` will repeat the `countdown` function infinitely.

To stop it, just use `clearInterval(timeout);`